# Referring to variable in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array called `eM`:

```
double[][][] eM = new double[4][4][4];
```

I also have a helper method to converts an `int`to a `char`:

```
public static char intToChar(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        return 'A';
    case 1:
        return 'B';
    case 2:
        return 'C';
    default:
        return 'D';
    }
}
```

I have four integer variables:

```
int A = 108;
int B = 299;
int C = 302;
int D = 411;
```

Now, here is the tricky part. I want to go through each index of the 3D array eM and multiply its index values. So that 
`[0][0][0] = 1*1*1 = 1; [0][0][1] = 1*1*2 = 2; ...; [3][3][3] = 4*4*4 = 64`.

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
        for (int k=0; k<4; k++){
            char I = intToChar(i);
            char J = intToChar(j);
            char K = intToChar(k);
            // Not sure what to do here
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need chars? `eM[i][j][k] = (i+1) * (j+1) * (k+1)` should do it

Comment: It's hard to tell what are you trying to do

Comment: You get the three chars corresponding to each index in the loop. Then what do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry I failed to explain correctly. Please see my edit and comments with Telthien :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to refer to A...D by index, so you need to index them in an array:

```
int[] d = {A, B, C, D};
```

which goes before the for loop. Then your for loop is easy:

```
eM[i][j][k] = d[i]*d[j]*d[k];
```

This will set each of the values at `(i,j,k)` to the corresponding A...D multiplicands.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote those values for example sake. I updated them to something else: int A = 108, int B =299, int C =302, int D =411. Actually, I am running the whole code in a big for loop and these four integer variables will change!! Thanks!

Comment: @user22 I'm not sure how that's relevant to your question - what are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @user2293732 how does it change the logic? still you wanna store the product in elements of array.

Comment: Sorry. I must not be good at explaining. Let me try again. Basically I have the 3D array eM (with 64 indices). Those 64 indices are actually representing all 3-digit combinations of the letters A, B, C, D. So basically eM[0][0][0] represents AAA, eM[0][0][1] represents AAB, eM[0][1][1] represents ABB, ..., eM[3][3][3] represents DDD. (Continued next comment...)

Comment: Now, I have integer values stored for A = 108, B = 299, C = 302, D = 411. Next, I am going through the 3D array eM and assigning values to it that are equal to the multiplication of its indices. So eM[0][0][0] = 108*108*108, eM[0][0][1] = 108*108*299, ..., eM[3][3][3] = 411*411*411. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @user22 I have edited my answer - perhaps you should edit your question for clarity?

Comment: Wow, thank you! I was definitely over-complicating it. I will remember that technique now. Yours is the simplest answer :o)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the values of the integers corresponding to the char corresponding to the index. I think you can delete the intToChar step and go directly for the integer value of the index you want.

```
public static int getIntValue(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        return 108;
    case 1:
        return 299;
    case 2:
        return 302;
    default:
        return 411;
    }
}



for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<4; k++){
                eM[i][j][k]= getIntValue(i) * getIntValue(j) * getIntValue(k);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ay89 Several changes since the original question && not very sure what the OP is asking

Comment: yes, OP is not clear about the question, so he has also earned some down-votes, i'll suggest u to either edit the answer or remove it

Comment: Sorry I failed to explain correctly. Please see my edit and comments with Telthien :)

Comment: @user2293732 Another try ;)

Comment: No prob ;) Anyways I didn't get the reason you change index to char and then char to int instead of just go index to int.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
char I = intToChar(i);
char J = intToChar(j);
char K = intToChar(k);
eM[i][j][k] =  I*J*K;
```

apart from that, you also should generalize the for loop for any size of 3D array.

```
for (int i=0; i<eM.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<eM[i].length; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<eM[i][j].length; k++){
                //here goes the logic
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I failed to explain correctly. Please see my edit and comments with Telthien :)

Comment: @user2293732 yes this is what the above answer doing already.

Answer (score 0):

final version, run with -ea vm options to show the asserts working

```
 import java.util.HashMap;


public class mult {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static char intToChar(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return 'A';
        case 1:
            return 'B';
        case 2:
            return 'C';
        default:
            return 'D';
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> lookup = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        lookup.put('A', 108);
        lookup.put('B', 299);
        lookup.put('C', 302);
        lookup.put('D', 411);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Integer[][][] eM=new Integer[4][4][4];
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
                for (int k=0; k<4; k++){
                  eM[i][j][k] = (lookup.get(intToChar(i))) * 
                          (lookup.get(intToChar(j))) *
                          (lookup.get(intToChar(k)));
                }
            }

    }

assert(eM[0][0][0] == 108*108*108);
assert(eM[0][0][1] == 108*108*299);
assert(eM[3][3][3] == 411*411*411);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Vorsprung! That is exactly what I needed. I will have to look more into HashMap! Thanks again!! :o)